# Using lmer to test group by time interactions?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, interaction, panel-data

I am running a brain imaging analysis in which I'd like to assess whether changes in brain activation over time vary as a function of diagnosis (2 categories: patients and controls). There are 184 subjects total; 110 have two timepoints, 74 have one timepoint. In addition to diagnosis by time interactions, I would like to assess the main effect of diagnosis and would therefore like to include all single timepoints in my analysis.

The 6 variables I have in my model are diagnosis, study site, age at baseline, sex, duration between baseline and follow up scans (this is 0 for subjects with one timepoint), and timepoint (baseline or follow-up; this is baseline for subjects with only one timepoint). My model is currently structured as follows:

```r
    lmer(activation ~ sex + ageAtBaseline + diagnosis + duration + 
    studySite + timepoint + diagnosis*timepoint + (1 | subjectId), 
    data = ActivationData, REML = FALSE)
```

As I understand it, this model is not symmetrical in that sex, age, duration, and site are modeled as predictors of the trajectory intercept, but not of the trajectory slope. This may be problematic since any level of deviation from this assumption (i.e., sex, age, duration, and site are not associated with how patients change over time) may potentially bias estimation results.

What changes to my model do I need to make to avoid these assumptions?

Comment: Three questions for clarification. First, how many cases do you have with activation measurements at both times? Second, if you're "assessing whether changes in brain activation over time vary as a function of diagnosis," what do you expect to gain by including patients with only the baseline activation values? Third, how many different types of "diagnosis" are there? Please provide this information by editing the question, as comments are often overlooked by site users and comments can sometimes be lost.

Comment: These changes have been made. Thanks!

Comment: Am I correct that "group" means the same as "diagnosis"? Are there only 2 "groups," or more than that?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Made the clarification in the original post. Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: What do you mean "sex, age, duration, and site are modeled as predictors of the trajectory intercept, but not of the trajectory slope" ? They are predictors of the outcome, while allowing for each subject to have their own intercept. If you want each subject to have their own slope then you can fit random slopes. Also, what are the dependencies among the predictors ? Is age is a confounder ? What about duration ? Could the diagnosis result in a different duration ?